# Scale a rectangle made of 4 Vector3s in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to scale a rectangle made of 4 vertexes in a list simply with the value 0.5. So I mean by that, just make it 0.5 units bigger. The new values should be stored in another list which I named list2 here.

My first thought was trying this:

```
foreach (Vector3 element in list)
{

if(element.x < 0 && element.z < 0)
{
list2.Add(new Vector3(element.x - 0.5f, 0, element.z - 0.5f));
}

else if(element.x > 0 && element.z > 0)
{
list2.Add(new Vector3(element.x + 0.5f, 0, element.z + 0.5f));
}

else if (element.x < 0 && element.z > 0)
{
list2.Add(new Vector3(element.x - 0.5f, 0, element.z + 0.5f));
}

else if (element.x > 0 && element.z < 0)
{
list2.Add(new Vector3(element.x + 0.5f, 0, element.z - 0.5f));
}
}
```

I firstly thought that's the way to go, but I realised it would be a problem if the elements are partially equal to 0.

My question now is, is there any way to scale Vector3 points and simply make them bigger or smaller, independing where they are in the coordinate system?

I googled already but only found a given function which helps to scale a Vector but its only scaling by multiplication with a factor and I want to scale it only with 0.5 units.

Maybe you guys can help a noob out. :D

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "scale with 0.5 units, does that mean you want the result to be 150% of the original, or 50%? In either case, I'm not sure why you can't use the "scaling by multiplication with a factor" solution that you say you've already found (where k=1.5 or k=0.5, respectively)

Comment: Secondly, where is the origin point of your scaling? The center of the rectangle? One of its vertices? One of its edges? Some fixed point in the world? The decision on that point is going to decide in which direction the rectangle grows/shrinks.

Comment: also do you mean `0.5` units bigger in each direction or per axis?

Comment: @Flater so basically to answer your question, I mean 1.5 by that and one vertex is 0, 0, 0, so this should be the origin point. Hope you get me now. ^^

Comment: @derHugo so if we have the following vectors: (0.0, 0.0, 0.0); (1.0, 0.0, 0.0); (1.0, 0.0, 1.0); (0.0, 0.0, 1.0); I want to transform them to (-0.5, 0.0, -0.5); (1.5, 0.0, -0.5); (1.5, 0.0, 1.5); (-0.5, 0.0, 1.5);.

Comment: @xnik do you know the order of vertices or do they come in random order?

Comment: @derHugo what do you mean by that? how they are sorted in the list?

Comment: @xnik yes exactly .. if you know the order and it is always the same you could go by index instead of using some conditions

Answer (score 2):

If you already know the order of vertices e.g. in your case counter-clockwise starting at bottom-left I wouldn't use a loop with conditions but rather directly do

```
public List<Vector3> ScaleRectangleByStep(List<Vector3> vertices, float step)
{
    // copy the given list
    var output = new List<Vector3>(vertices);

    output[0] = output[0] - Vector3.right * step - Vector3.forward * step;
    output[1] = output[1] + Vector3.right * step - Vector3.forward * step;
    output[2] = output[2] + Vector3.right * step + Vector3.forward * step;
    output[3] = output[3] - Vector3.right * step + Vector3.forward * step;

    return output;
}
```

If you don't know the order you would rather somehow get center position in order to check

```
public List<Vector3> ScaleRectangleByStep(List<Vector3> vertices, float step)
{
    // copy the given list
    var output = new List<Vector3>(vertices);

    // Get the center of the rectangle
    var center = Vector3.zero;
    foreach(var vertex in output)
    {
        center += vertex;
    }
    center /= output.Count;

    // in a second run use the center for your conditions
    for(var i = 0; i < output.Count; i++)
    {
        var vertex = output[i];

        if(vertex.x < center.x)
        {
            vertex.x -= step;
        }
        else if(vertex.x > center.x)
        {
            vertex.x += step;
        }

        if(vertex.z < center.z)
        {
            vertex.z -= step;
        }
        else if(vertex.z > center.z)
        {
            vertex.z += step;
        }

        // the else cases would basically mean that the vertices 
        // are equal to the center ... 

        output[i] = vertex;
    }

    return output;
}
```

Or as a complete alternative if instead of moving the borders by certain units you rather want to scale by a certain factor I would rather do it like

```
public List<Vector3> ScaleRectangleByFactor(List<Vector3> vertices, float multiplicationFactor)
{
    // copy the given list
    var output = new List<Vector3>(vertices);

    // first find the center position
    var center = Vector3.zero;
    foreach(var vertex in output)
    {
       center += vertex;
    }
    center /= list.Count;

    // Now scale every vertex relative to the center position with the given factor
    for(var i = 0; i < output.Count; i++)
    {
        // Get the position relative to the center
        var relativePosition = (output[i] - center);
        // scale it up by the given factor
        relativePosition *= multiplicationFactor;
        // assign it back to the list
        output[i] = center + relativePosition;
    }    

    return output;
}
```